# iOS: play sound for duration in background

Tags: ios, avaudioplayer, background-process

I wondering if there was a way to play a sound or music for a predetermined duration even if the app is put into the background.

For instance, say the sound is 30 mins long but only want to play it for 10 mins, how can I pause the sound while in the background.  Or is there a way to tell AVAudioPlayer to loop 0.333 times?

Is there a better class to use instead of AVAudioPlayer to achieve this?

EDIT:
So far I've searched SO and Google to no avail. And have been reading through Apple's docs.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Two solutions:-

-1. You can have Local and Push Notification

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH1-SW1

Notification can play sound when delivered.

-2. You can make you app run in background and play sound

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html

iOS/iTunes rules limit what you can do in background to pass moderation but it mentions playing music.

Comment: Im sorry if my question was misleading, but what i am trying to achieve is to play a song that mite be 30 mins long in the background for only 10 mins.  The problem i'm running into is that a NSTimer is not allowed to run in the bg, therefore i was wondering is there was a way to initialize the AVAudioPlayer or some other class to play the song for some predetermined length.

Comment: You can play silent file for 10 mins ))) You should use second option

Comment: I dont think you understand what I mean, im trying the play a song that is 30 mins long for 10 mins

Comment: Is there no way you can not use a 10 minute audio file? I do not really know the ins and outs of AV, but can you possibly cut up the audio and save it as a new one to be played for 10 minutes?

Comment: @DanClarke  thats what i figured i had to do, i just gotta figure how to do it, hopefully with out anyway low level apis

Comment: You can pack that silent file in your app or generate on fly. Or have 1 minute silent file and play it 10 times. It is easy to generate raw silent file. It is just 000000000. But I think you will need encoded audio file MP3 or M4A.